# Can't switch to performance mode on Nvidia X Server on 16.04 after CUDA install

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda

I followed the CUDA installation tutorial from the [official NVidia guide](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1604&target_type=deblocal) but I'm having a problem with switching from power saving mode to performance mode. I tried to log out and login as intructed and tried to reboot but it doesn't save the settings.

[image: My Nvidia X Server Settings]

I've also tried to run

```
$nvidia-smi

nvidia-smi: command not found
```

This is whats happens when i run nvidia-settings

```
$nvidia-settings
RROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


ERROR: Error querying enabled displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).


ERROR: Error querying connected displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).

** Message: PRIME: Requires offloading
** Message: PRIME: is it supported? yes

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file. This file should have been installed along with this driver at /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The application
       profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be prepopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text. Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.
```

I have a Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050.

Comment: Same problem here. I'll let you know if I get anywhere with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this same problem when trying to install Nvidia Docker, it turned out I had version 384 and Nvidia Docker installed version 387, which meant that I now had to different nvidia drivers installed in my system.

To solve this just purge both drivers:

[Uninstall the nvidia driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)

And reinstalled it fromt the tutorial:

[NVIDIA CUDA Installation Guide for Linux](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html)