# Restore Ubuntu from recovery mode

Tags: 14.04, restore, recovery-mode

I wanted to change the graphics driver from "nouveau" to "nvidia". I restarted my computer but as soon as I log in, the graphics engine does not launch and I get the login screen again. I do not have anything important on my machine, how to reset Linux from recovery mode ?

Thanks for all,
Jean.

Answer (score 0):

So you got the classic "Login Screen Loop" that happened to me once, you can find the Commands you gotta perform in this page: [How can I uninstall a nvidia driver completely ?](https://askubuntu.com/q/206283/823432) , since to solve that problem, you have to remove everything related to Nvidia with `remove -- purge` . I hope that Helps.