# multiple nvidia errors but my display adapter is not nvidia

Tags: drivers, graphics

18.04 4.15.0-23
My log has many entries snipped to below. 
Where is the modprobe for nvidia coming from and how do I turn it off? Or is there some other issue?

```
systemd-udevd[1983]: Process '/sbin/modprobe nvidia-modeset' failed with exit code 1.
kernel: nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 239
kernel: NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter found!
kernel: nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 239
```

My video is intel :

```
   lshw -class display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
```

using intel driver

```
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0


lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia              14352384  1
ipmi_msghandler        53248  2 nvidia,ipmi_devintf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log no longer includes the messages. I followed Fred's procedure outlined here

[How can I uninstall a nvidia driver completely ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)

I am using MATE so instead of re-installing the Ubuntu desktop I re-installed mate-desktop.