# Ubuntu drivers sees drivers I dont have

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, kubuntu, dpkg

If I run `ubuntu-drivers list` the output is:

```
bcmwl-kernel-source
nvidia-driver-396
nvidia-driver-390
nvidia-340
```

No clue what bcmwl is, but nvidia drivers 340 and 390 I have uninstalled. Why are they still displayed?

Comment: Probably means those versions are available, not necessarily installed, and bcmwl is a Broadcom wireless driver.

Comment: try something like this `apt-cache policy nvidia-driver-390`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in ubuntu-drivers in my opinion. I've also seen two separate instances of the same problem where the `ubuntu-drivers list` command gave the following output:

```
nvidia-driver-390
nvidia-340
```

However only nvidia-driver-390 was actually installed.

Because one of the systems that produced this unexpected output was my own, I ran `apt policy nvidia-340` and got the following results.

```
$ apt policy nvidia-340
nvidia-340:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 340.106-0ubuntu3
```

nvidia-340 had been installed on my system at one time, but it was removed when after I upgraded it to nvidia-driver-390. The bug appears to be that `ubuntu-drivers list` does not know that nvidia-340 has been removed.

In the other instance of this problem that I know about `ubuntu-drivers list` produced the same output as shown above in the second paragraph, and once again `apt policy nvidia-340` showed that nvidia-340 was not installed.

Comment: I'm going to mark as true as I suspect you're right even though I don't know 100%. All the drivers listed I had previously installed.

Answer (score 0):

When you typed your command it listed what is installed. In my case:

```
$ ubuntu-drivers list
nvidia-384
```

In your case you appear to have three nVidia drivers installed; `nvidia-driver-396`, `nvidia-driver-390` and `nvidia-340`.

Additionally you have a WiFi driver (I believe) installed called: 'bcmwl'.

To completely remove your nVidia drivers you need to refer to: [How can I uninstall a nvidia driver completely ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely).