# Can I remove "Nvidia X Server Settings" from startup?

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, startup

I removed my nvidia GPU now I use intel's integrated gpu on my CPU. Can I remove "Nvidia X Server Settings" from startup in this case?

Comment: If you are not using nvidia anymore why not [uninstall nvidia driver completely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely/206289#206289).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use this driver anymore, you can remove without any problems in your computer, but you can also uninstall completely the driver, it doesn't have utility anymore.