# How do i cleanse the 'additional drivers' menu in software and updates

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

So I've stumbled my way through trying to download drivers for my graphics card, and at this point, in the additional drivers menu in software and updates, I no longer have any idea which one i'm looking for.  Old versions no longer present on my computer at all still show up on the list. How can I cleanse/refresh this so that It only shows the currently usable drivers? Heres an image:

[image: here]

Comment: Purge the drivers you dont need anymore [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)

Comment: The drivers were already purged, but persist in the menu

Comment: To remove the ppa run 'sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa'