# Nvidia-detector display different driver version of nvidia-smi

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have recently changed my Nvidia GPU, and I am having problems to boot Ubuntu. I get a blank screen after GRUB.

When I boot in recovery mode (it works) and type the command `nvidia-detector`, I get:

```
nvidia-driver-440
```

And when I type `nvidia-smi`, I get:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.50       Driver Version: 430.50       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro M5000        Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  Off |
| 39%   45C    P8    15W / 150W |    408MiB /  8123MiB |      1%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

I followed [[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)], [[2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162078#162078)], and [[3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics)] to completely uninstall the drivers and then install it again.

**My question is:** Does anyone know why Ubuntu is showing two different driver versions, and how can I solve it?

Comment: @Vimeiro did you manage to fix this issue? I'm having a similar problem with 435 installed but nvidia-detector detecting 440.

Comment: @LiamBaker, I completely removed **everything** related to Nvidia, and installed the Nvidia driver again from PPA repository [[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)]. I followed the tutorials I mentioned above and also these ones [[2](https://medium.com/devoops-and-universe/installation-of-cuda-toolkit-on-linux-54765a3e3c7d)], [[3](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/12/09/how-to-install-tensorflow-2-0-on-ubuntu)], [[4](https://www.tengio.com/blog/getting-caffe-for-ai-working-on-linux/)]. They are related to ML but have drivers installation steps as well.

Comment: The tool is broken. Plain and simple. I would rely on `nvidia-smi` due to its maturity and more info it provides.