# One screen on two displayed and wrong resolution

Tags: dual-boot, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

I have recently installed ubuntu in dual boot with windows 10 and everything was working, until I switched on the computer and ubuntu was 1024x768 instead of 1920x1080 and only one monitor was connected. How can I fix this?

Comment: Which GPU does your machine have? Might need to install/apply GPU drivers.

Comment: @Alex I have Nvidia something.... before this happened, i’ve installed gpu drivers, is that the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was indeed the nvidia drivers I've installed before. This is how to remove them: [How can I uninstall a nvidia driver completely ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)