# Ubuntu doesn't start after login screen, can't access shell

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, login

After trying to install a new driver for my graphics card GeForce MX250 from the official Nvidia website (which was working until I turned my computer off), I can't get my computer to start anymore.
After accessing the login screen and login in to my user account, the screen turns black.

I've read that I should remove the new driver and install one of the official package manager, but I just can't open a terminal so I'm somewhat lost.

I tried every possible combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>.
But no terminal is appearing. 
I can't get out of the GUI. It's either that or a blank screen.

I also tried to access some kind of terminal from the gnu grub version 2.02 page which I can access during booting. I'm sorry, I don't really know if this is supposed to work anyway, but as possible boot options, I only got Ubuntu, which brought me back to the login screen.

I really hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally managed to solve my problem.
I could get into recovery mode by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> while starting my computer. I landed in the wrong menu because of pressing it too often, so just pressing it very slowly solved this. From the grub menu I started recovery mode. Then I chose options grub and network to be able to use the Internet. Then I started a root shell session.
Afterwards I followed the answer provided to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely).
I'm pretty sure my problem was that ubuntu-desktop must have been removed by my purging of all nvidia modules before I installed the new driver in the first place.

After a reboot my system was working again and I could install a nvidia driver again using

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

(which is the same as before, so I really think it had to do with ubuntu-desktop).