# Asus FX553VE, USB ports and integrated keyboard not getting powered after nvidia drivers update

Tags: drivers, nvidia, usb, keyboard

**I'm a Linux beginner so please be patient with me**

So I tried to install ubuntu 18.04 on my ASUS FX553VE Laptop, after the installation completed I decided to install nvidia drivers for my GTX 1050 Ti mobile GPU by using the Software Updater Utility software and install nvidia-drivers-440 (recomended) optional package.

After reboot none of my USB 2.0/3.0 ports were working, as well as my integrated keyboard and the SDcard slot. The only thing that work is my touchpad.
So the only way i can interact with my machine is to use visual keyboard and the touchpad.
The problem is ocure even before ubuntu boots up, I can't press any keys to get to the BIOS or to change GRUB config before startup.
External keyboards don't seems to get any power from USB ports too.

I tried to purge nvidia drivers by doing so :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
echo 'nouveau' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

*source : [How can I uninstall a nvidia driver completely ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)*

That did nothing.

I also tried to boot up from my sdcard slot with a freshly flashed Ubuntu iso on it, like the USB ports, no power is getting through it.

`lsusb` command return nothing as well as `dmesg | grep -i usb`

Maybe the problem is comming from a bad power management due to incompatible GPU drivers ?

here's a `dmesg` log : https://semestriel.framapad.org/p/r.ea3bdd6eb84591447693f06547c2dc8b

Any help would be appreciated.