# Nvidia X-server setting is blank

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 20.04, nvidia-prime

After changing to Intel (Power Saving Mode), Nvidia X-server setting is not showing anything. I need to active GPU now but can't activate it.

```
$ sudo lshw -c display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 5500
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:50 memory:99000000-99ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GK208BM [GeForce 920M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:9a000000-9affffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:9b000000-9b07ffff



$ sudo nvidia-settings 

ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


(nvidia-settings:45705): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:53:23.943: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 16:53:23.948: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 16:53:23.948: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem after a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install.

Running `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by installing another version of Nvidia driver. I am not sure about whether this error will appear again.

Comment: Which other version of the NVIDIA driver did you install? What commands did you use to install this other version? Did you remove the old NVIDIA driver?

Comment: I removed all nvidia related driver previously installed. Then installed another version of nvidia driver from `additional driver` in `software & updates`.

Comment: Thank you. How did you remove all previously installed nvidia-related drivers?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely This question's  answer helped me

Comment: @SayedSohan when i opened `additional drivers` in `software & updates`, it says `no additional driver available`

Comment: @IsraelObanijesu maybe your gpu isn't recognized.. try install gpu directly from nvidia website or reinstall os.

Comment: Ah, gave up on it already, all i wanted to do is change the overscan for my TV when using HDMI but it is not that important to the extent of reinstalling my os

Answer (score 0):

You could have just changed the Nvidia setting via command line by using:

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

Then it would have gone back to Nvidia mode.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me (a problem linked to ubuntu-drivers-common package updating) :

Use this command to open the /usr/bin/prime-supported file:

```
xed admin:///usr/bin/prime-supported
```

Change this line:

```
if [ -e "/var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/requires_offloading" ]; then
```

To this:

```
if [ -e "/var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/requires_offloading" || true ]; then
```

source : https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1970510&sid=2e76739afd221ba2200fddbfdb7a040d#p1970510

Answer (score -1):

Your graphics isn't recognized.

I just reinstalled OS and mark "install third party software".

After that, do not install any other graphic driver. You will run on Intel choosen by Ubuntu.  Nothing other works like this solution.

PS: When you reinstall, you can choose in Nvidia x server settings " Power saving mode".

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed this issue by installing another version of Nvidia driver. I am not sure about whether this error will appear again.