# Wi-Fi disappeared after driver installation/update - Intel AX200 / iwlwifi with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers, wireless, 20.04

I'm pretty new to Linux outside of virtual machines, first of all, so I'm sorry if any descriptions of my problem are trivial or if I forgot something. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with Windows 10 on dual boot on my Desktop PC. Fast boot on Windows 10 is disabled.

My kernel version is `Linux 5.4.0-54-generic`.

I intended to update my graphics card drivers (RTX 2070) today as Ubuntu seemed a bit laggy to me. I used `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` to install my drivers.

`ubuntu-drivers devices` showed following drivers for my graphics card:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:26:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001E84sv00001462sd0000C726bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : TU104 [GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER]
manual_install: True
driver   : nvidia-driver-440-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-455 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-450 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

After rebooting, Wi-Fi, using the Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 networking card (iwlwifi), stopped working for Ubuntu. On Windows it's working fine though. Wi-Fi worked fine on Ubuntu also before using `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. I can't tell anything about Bluetooth, as I have never used Bluetooth before.

Using `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` or `lspci -v`, the card is still showing up.
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQaKQ.png) [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJBuR.png)

I noticed that `lspci -v` is not showing a `Kernel driver in use` for this device? What can I do with this information?

- `lsmod | grep iwl` returns nothing, neither does
- `rfkill list all` (neither Wi-Fi nor Bluetooth) or
- `sudo find /sys | grep drivers.*21:00` (regarding the number shown at the `lspci` command).

`sudo modinfo iwlwifi` shows `modinfo: ERROR: Module iwlwifi not found.`. Similarly, `modprobe iwlwifi` shows that it could not find a module by the name iwlwifi.

There are `iwlwifi*.ucode` files at `/lib/firmware` or `/usr/lib/firmware`.

Ubuntu's Software Center does not show the AX200 card under "Additional drivers" though.

Any clue how I can get my Wi-Fi to work again? I don't have any internet on my Linux machine at the moment, as it is not possible for me to use Ethernet from where I am now.

I'm thankful for any help.

Comment: What results for `dpkg -l | grep linux-modules-extra`

Comment: Disable Windows Fast Startup feature.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after running sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall. This solution worked for me:
[No Wi-Fi settings or connection after switching to NVIDIA graphics driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286738/no-wi-fi-settings-or-connection-after-switching-to-nvidia-graphics-driver)

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-52-generic
```

Comment: I am using MSI Mag X570 MoBo with Ryz 9-3900. installing modules-extra fixed this issue. Thank you samsam!