# internet not working in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, nvidia, internet, realtek-wireless

I recently installed `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` and after the reboot, my internet is not working.

The Network tab in settings only shows VPN. (Previously my LAN and wifi settings were shown here)

Searching for Wifi in settings shows `No Wi-Fi Adapter Found`

`ifconfig` only shows `lo` and not `wlan0` nor `eth0`

`sudo lshw -C network` shows that both `Ethernet Controller` and `Network Controller` is `UNCLAIMED`

Ive tried installing `firmware-b43-installer_019-4_all.deb` which required `b43-fwcutter_019-4_amd64.deb` but this tries to download `broadcom-wl-5.100.148.tar`

Both my wifi and ethernet adapters are of Realtek.

I've tried using usb tethering from my phone but it's not being detected either.

I've windows installed on the same system and booting to windows, everything is working fine.

Please help. I'm typing this from my phone  as I have absolutely no way of connecting to the internet from my ubuntu

[image]

Comment: What are the Realtek / Broadcom chips in your computer? Please edit your question and add all the new information. Also search this site for the chip number.

Comment: @user68186II've added a picture of bother the interface

Comment: @user68186 this did not work.. my `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` already had the content as answered in the post. my kernel version is 5.8.0-45-generic. Very frustrating..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No Wi-Fi settings or connection after switching to NVIDIA graphics driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286738/no-wi-fi-settings-or-connection-after-switching-to-nvidia-graphics-driver)

Comment: @user68186 Thanks,, had came across this post yesterday and it helped me.. I've posted the same post in the answer

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286738/no-wi-fi-settings-or-connection-after-switching-to-nvidia-graphics-driver) had the same problem as mine.

I downloaded the [extra drivers](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-updates-main-amd64/linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-36-generic_5.8.0-36.40%7E20.04.1_amd64.deb.html) from my phone and installed it and after a reboot, its working now.