# Wifi adapter not found ubuntu 22.04 on laptop with Intel wifi ax200

Tags: drivers, wireless, bluetooth

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop Lenovo Legion s7 no dual boot only Linux. After installing the Nvidia drivers from Ubuntu Software & Update version `NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-525 (proprietary)`

After installing drivers and rebooting wifi adaptor and bluetooth not found, and touchpad is not working.

I tried to delete nvidia drivers, with `sudo apt-get --purge remove "*nvidia*"`

The biggest issue is that I can not update or upgrade anything because of lack of internet. I can not even use ethernet.

I can not even connect to internet sharing it via usb from phone. But the usb is working.

Troubleshooting:

ifconfig -a

```
Command 'ifconfig' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install net-tools
```

sudo lshw -c network

```
[sudo] password for eadmin:

  *-network UNCLAIMED      

       description: Network controller

       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200

       vendor: Intel Corporation

       physical id: 0

       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0

       version: 1a

       width: 64 bits

       clock: 33MHz

       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list

       configuration: latency=0

       resources: memory:fd700000-fd703fff
```

rfkill list all - no output

lspci -nnk | grep Net

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)

                Subsystem: Rivet Networks Killer™ Wi-Fi 6 AX1650x (AX200NGW) [1a56:1654]
```

lsusb

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 003 Device 004: ID 048d:c967 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. ITE Device(8296)

Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f2:b67d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera

Bus 003 Device 002: ID 09da:0025 A4Tech Co., Ltd. A4tech 2.4G Wireless Device

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8564:1000 Transcend Information, Inc. JetFlash

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c4b Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. AX200 Bluetooth

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

sudo dmesg | grep iwl - no output

sudo dmesg | grep wifi - no output

uname -r

```
5.19.0-38-generic
```

uname -a

```
Linux user 5.19.0-38-generic #39~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Mar 17 21:16:15 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What I've tried:

sudo rfkill unblock all

install drivers for  Wi-Fi 6 AX200 following this guide
https://itslinuxfoss.com/install-intel-wifi-6-ax200-driver/

How can I repair fix the issue?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` and also: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status` Can you select an earlier kernel version at the GRUB menu and boot into it? Does the wireless work in the earlier version?

Comment: Faced with exactly the same problem. Did you fix this issue?

Comment: @korst1k Please start your own new question.

Comment: I found solution here:
[https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286738/no-wi-fi-settings-or-connection-after-switching-to-nvidia-graphics-driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286738/no-wi-fi-settings-or-connection-after-switching-to-nvidia-graphics-driver)