# x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS after the latest OS update

Tags: bios, amdgpu, sgx

Ubuntu 20.04 installed latest OS patch, and I am now getting the following errors on boot-up. The main problem is now my Dell D3100 dual monitor drivers stopped working. I installed the latest D3100 drivers to no avail.

PC specs:

Lenovo Flex 4
  AMD Radeon Graphics
  Intel Core 7 7th gen

[image]

Comment: These are not errors and nothing is to be done.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SGX disabled by BIOS message on Ubuntu 20.04 booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418992/sgx-disabled-by-bios-message-on-ubuntu-20-04-booting)