# Message when Boot: x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, sgx

Every time when I boot my computer, I receive the following message:

```
[    0.108927] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
[    0.249942] platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 1: [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed40fff]
[    0.249949] acpi MSFT0101:00: platform device creation failed: -16
```

Until now, I'm still able to use the computer, despite the message;
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

I tried `fsck /dev/sda5`, but it said that I had to unmount the partition, I used the command umount `/dev/sda5`,but it seems to be busy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SGX disabled by BIOS message on Ubuntu 20.04 booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418992/sgx-disabled-by-bios-message-on-ubuntu-20-04-booting)

Comment: Partially, now it doesn't show the SGX message, but still shows the other messages about the MSFT0101

Comment: Regarding others see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot