# Ubuntu Installer Stuck and Wont Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi

A bit of background:
I've recently tried to install Ubuntu as a dual boot to replace my NixOS system. I currently have a NixOS/Windows 11 setup, and I wish to make it an Ubuntu/Windows 11 setup.

Now, onto the problem:
I've created a flash drive using Rufus of Ubuntu LTS (22.4.03) and tried to boot into it in the BIOS. I have Secure Boot set to Other OS (which should mean it's disabled per my understanding). Upon booting, I have chosen "Try or Install Ubuntu". It then loads a black screen which writes SGX is disabled by BIOS and then just stops. I've tried letting it sit there for 10 mins or so but it did not do anything significant.

Any ideas what causes this or how I can troubleshoot this issue? I have already re-downloaded the ISO and re-used Rufus, although I might still be missing something.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this help? [SGX disabled by BIOS message on Ubuntu 20.04 booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418992/sgx-disabled-by-bios-message-on-ubuntu-20-04-booting)

Comment: @mpboden thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, enabling it is NOT possible (only the Software Controlled and Disable options are available). Also, I've read some things saying that the SGX problem itself is not supposed to cause problems booting, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: You weren't specific as to what Ubuntu 22.04 LTS product you're talking about (Server and thus the `subiquity` installer, Desktop and thus `ubiquity`, or a *flavor* etc), but Ubuntu is QA tested & will install with Secure-Boot *enabled*. As `rufus` can reformat ISOs though, use appropriate settings for your chosen release & ensure it's updated (*or just clone the ISO to media which is `dd` I think in rufus terminology*)

Comment: Hey @guiverc, sorry for not specifying. I downloaded Ubuntu Desktop. I did install a brand new Rufus and made sure the settings are okay via 2 different tutorials (said to only change the partition scheme and leave everything as default). They might be mistaken though.