# Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't load after installing Nvidia 535 driver and stuck at black screen of death

Tags: boot, drivers, 20.04, nvidia, graphics

I just installed the graphics drivers for my computer (ASUS ROG STRIX G15, RTX 2070, intel I7) and now the screen stops at a blinking dash during boot... I tried [this](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/black-screen-after-install-of-nvidia-driver-ubuntu/109312) and also tried enabling SGX in my BIOS (since it's showing a SGX warning), but my BIOS doesn't have a SGX option... None fixed the problem.

[**This is the tutorial I followed**](https://youtu.be/OFWKevbjDPU?si=3yEE_9Yd2B-lj2tz) to install the driver. Do you guys know how we can fix this?

Down below I attached images of how my screen looks like on boot and when I [check to see what driver version I have](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a clean Ubuntu reinstall (it's a dual boot with windows 11), and this time I installed the 5**25** driver version**and it worked flawlessly**. I did this since it was simpler than messing with more installs/uninstalls

Answer (score 0):

A wild-ass guess on a possible help forward:

`sudo apt purge nividia-driver-535` <kbd>Enter</kbd>
I'd expect this to remove most if not all of the driver and it's related packages. When all is removed you have "a clean slate" to start trying with another driver.

Check that all has been removed with `dpkg -l |  grep -i nvidia`, if anything still has **`ii`** in the leftmost column, then `purge` it too (as above).

As no nvidia packages  remain, try a reboot; I'd expect the "nouveau" driver to be active again.

In that state, feel free to try either 535 once again, maybe there was a mishap the first time - that prevented it to install correctly...
OR try an older one, which might work.

Repeat the purge if it still fails to boot into the GUI.

*NOTE: there are "open" and "server" versions of the driver and also those that have no such designation (maybe call these "desktop"), avoid at least "server" - unless it IS a server.*

And last but not least; that tutorial is "good", 'OK' to use that method to install the driver.

But: If you write down the driver name and use `sudo apt install _driver_name_` you will see a lot more information. Among that information you will most likely have some kind of indication on WHAT the problem is, if there is a problem.