# Facing Boot and Device Issues after Removing NVIDIA Drivers on Kubuntu

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, kubuntu

I have a dual boot setup with Windows 11 and Kubuntu 23.10. My laptop is a Lenovo IdeaPad 5 Pro 16ACH6 (model with GeForce RTX 3050).

I tried to remove all NVIDIA drivers because my battery drains much faster on Kubuntu than on Windows, and I understood that the issue might be related to the graphics card.

I simply used the remove command (and then autoremove afterward) with the NVIDIA wildcard indicated here: [How can I uninstall a nvidia driver completely ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)

However, after rebooting, I encounter ACPI errors, and the OS refuses to start, even if I add acpi=off and noapic to the grub options.

I tried booting into recovery mode and then booting normally from recovery. It works, but when I reach my desktop, none of my devices work (Wi-Fi, trackpad, Bluetooth, etc.). So, I'm unable to connect to the internet to perform an apt upgrade.

When I run ifconfig, I only see "lo" displayed.

I'm not sure what to do anymore. I don't have an Ethernet port on my PC, and even with a Type-C adapter, I don't have the eth0 interface available.

Any ideas? I feel like it also removed all the drivers for my devices...

Comment: Look in `/var/log/dpkg.log`, make a note of all packages that you uninstalled today, then reinstall them. According to your link, you might have removed your desktop environment, so you want to do `sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Hmm I checked and I haven't removed kubuntu-desktop, since it is not in the list of removed packages and it says that it is already the newest version. Also I tried to reinstall all removed packages but it doesn't work since I don't have internet connection.

Comment: You can download the .debs onto a USB using another computer or the LiveCD, then install them by passing the all at once to `dpkg -i`

Comment: Some of the .debs are not found when I try to download them. However, nvidia drivers are fine and I'm able to install them in Kubuntu. But I still can't use my WiFi or any of my devices on Kubuntu..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried booting into terminal only?
In grub options there is a line starting with `linux`, add a number `3` to the end of the line to boot into level 3 (terminal only, no graphics)(keep `acpi=off` and `noapic`) and let the device boot.
Better instructions: [How to boot into command line?](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/boot-linux-command-line-mode)
You should end up in a login shell with your default network settings applied and you can also change the settings, after logging in, to connect to the internet.
[Configure WiFi Connections](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/networkmanager/configure-wifi-connections)

Comment: I can boot into terminal only and login, but same problem when I type `nmcli d` I don't see my wifi interface, and there's no result to `nmcli d wifi list`