How do I remove nvidia drivers installed with ubuntu-drivers install?
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.  I installed the nvidia drivers with
sudo ubuntu-drivers install --gpgpu nvidia:535-server

But the ubuntu-drivers command doesn't have a way to remove drivers that it installed.  I can see them in use with this:
lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia_uvm           1798144  0
nvidia_drm             94208  1
nvidia_modeset       1314816  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              56811520  2 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        274432  5 drm_display_helper,amdgpu,nvidia_drm
drm                   765952  18 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,drm_suballoc_helper,drm_display_helper,nvidia,drm_buddy,amdgpu,drm_ttm_helper,nvidia_drm,ttm,amdxcp
video                  73728  2 amdgpu,nvidia_modeset

The software updater shows that I have a manually installed driver so it is no use.  I've tried sudo apt remove --purge nvidia* but it does nothing since it didn't install the drivers.
How do I remove and purge nvidia drivers installed with ubuntu-drivers install?

never use "*" with apt.  and see https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely  If you want to use ubuntu-drivers you need to install another to remove the current one. "distro free builtin" is the default one

the apt command is sudo apt purge '^nvidia-.*'  and not sudo apt remove --purge nvidia*
